# variable number of arguments over network

Tags: c++, network-programming, boost-asio

I am trying to make a client server application with boost asio library. At first I have designed the program to send request and response with same pattern and same length, that is there is a delimiter character and between each parameter I put this delimiter to separate parameters and on the server side I parse the incoming stream according to delimiter parameter. 
The problem is as the program grows I realized that it is not a good idea to send every parameter on each request/response, because there are lots of parameters and only few of them are necessary depending of the type of the request/response. So my question is what kind of design would be good to send variable number of arguments over network?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a hierarchy of messages with the message id as mentioned below.

```
struct Msg{
    int msg_id;
    type t1;
    type t2;
}

struct init_Msg : public Msg{
   type init_param;
}

struct inti end_Msg : public Msg{
   type end_param;
}
```

Then you can create a specific message with the message id at the client side. Serialize it and send it over network to server. On the server side, you can deserialize it and can use message id to identify the type of message. 
To serialize the data you can use a third party library called protobuf.
check out https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/

Answer (score 1):

If the data size is small I wouldn't mind a text based solution.
Just write/read the data one property
(= name: + value) each line.
Maybe even use xml. There are libraries to read/write that.

Comment: do you know the name of any of these libraries?